# VisualForce page styling

Tags: visualforce, lightning, salesforce-classic

How can I dynamically change the styling on the VisualForce Page depending on the Lightning/ Classic.As we are in the process of migrating from Classic to Lightning we want the VF page to be compatible in both the User Interfaces. I am trying to set the div tag based on the UI Theme detection

```
              <div style= "{IF($User.UIThemeDisplayed == 'Theme3'? 'position:relative;left:150': 'position:relative;left:400px')}">
              <apex:outputLabel value="ABC"></apex:outputLabel>
              </div>
```

I even tried doing like

```
              <apex:outputPanel >
              <apex:outputPanel rendered="{! $User.UIThemeDisplayed == 'Theme4d' }">                  
              <div style= "position:relative;left:400">
              <apex:outputLabel value="ABC -Lightning"/>
              </div> 
              </apex:outputPanel>
              <apex:outputPanel rendered="{! $User.UIThemeDisplayed == 'Theme3' }">
              <div style= "position:relative;left:150">
              <apex:outputLabel value="ABC - Classic"/>
              </div> 
              </apex:outputPanel>
              </apex:outputPanel>
```

But there is no change in the Alignment, it just shows the text towards the left in both the UI

Answer (score 0):

You should use the lightningStylesheets tag in your page markup:

```
<apex:page controller="myController" lightningStylesheets="{!renderLightning}">
```

With the renderLightning variable defined in myController class. This will give you dynamic styling based on if the current user is in lightning experience or not.
For more information, check out the documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/vf_dev_best_practices_slds_lightningstylesheets.htm) and this [blog post](http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2015/11/context-is-everything.html)

Comment: But this UI detection works within VF Page, I am just not able to get it working in the div tags

Answer (score 0):

your if condition is not correct. Please try below

```
    "IF('{!$User.UIThemeDisplayed}' == 'Theme4d'? 
    'position:relative;left:150': 'position:relative;left:400px')}"
```